# How to italicize the ® symbol in html?

Tags: html, css

I've tried `<em>` tags and `font-style: italic`, trying both `®` and `&reg;` with no success.

One "workaround" I know of is using an external library of symbols such as `<i class="far fa-registered"></i>` from [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons/registered?style=regular), but would prefer to not have to load any external sources.

Is it possible to italicize that text symbol at all?

Comment: Out of interest can I ask why you want to do this? It wouldn't have occurred to me to even try because I think of it more like a logo than a letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approximate<sup>1</sup> it with skew:

```css
.italic span {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
}
.italic {
 font-style:italic;
}
```

```html
<div><span>&reg;</span> some text</div>

<div class="italic"><span>&reg;</span> some text</div>
```

<sup>1: as commented by @Bailey Parker, some font may contain the italicized version of ®. In such case, no need any workaround.</sup>

Comment: Oof, that's a brutal hack... Probably won't work with all fonts, as different fonts use different degrees of tilt.

Comment: @HereticMonkey that's why it's only an approximation ;)

Comment: Sure, just... makes my eye twitch... but that might be something else :).

Comment: You may want to change the `font-family`. The default font on FF (Times) has an italicized (R) glyph, so your skew is just stretching it more. Arial doesn't appear to have this glyph.

Comment: @BaileyParker what version of FF? I don't have this on my FF

Comment: Latest FF on macOS. The code snippets have no font family so it falls back to the browser's default, which is `serif`. `serif` on my machine is Times (Times New Roman on Windows), which has the italicized glyph. If this is a system difference, perhaps its even more illustrative to use a web font that is specifically chosen for its lack of an italicized (R). It seems that [Lato](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato) lacks italicized glyphs for (R).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, that font has italic version what you are using there.. So it could work. If you are using the google font then load the italic version too there.

Answer (score 1):

As @TemaniAfif pointed out, you can work around this. But, your root problem likely is the font family you're using doesn't have an italicized variety of the ® glyph. If you look at the fonts on your computer, you'll see multiple versions of each: "Arial Regular," "Arial Italic," "Arial Bold," "Arial Bold Italic." When you do `font-style: italic`, you're really just switching to using the "Arial Italic" font. If you then add `font-weight: bold`, then you switch to the "Arial Bold Italic." If you open up each of these with a font inspector and look at the glyphs, you'll notice that all of these fonts contain separate entries for each glyph (letters, numbers, symbols, etc.). So "Arial Regular" has an "a" glyph and so does "Arial Italic." Trying on my machine, Arial Italic does not appear to have a ® glyph. I believe when a font lacks a glyph, it falls back to the "regular" version of that font, and if that doesn't have the glyph it uses a system font containing these symbols. We can see this behavior if we try both Arial and Helvetica. Arial doesn't have a ® italicized glyph but Helvetica does. Times (the macOS version of Times New Roman) also appears to have an italicized ® glyph.

```css
div {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div style="font-family: Arial;">&reg; 2019 The quick brown fox (Arial)</div>
<div style="font-family: Helvetica;">&reg; 2019 The quick brown fox (Helvetica)</div>
<div style="font-family: Times;">&reg; 2019 The quick brown fox (Times, macOS only)</div>
```

So, the real solution here is to make sure you're using a font family that has an italicized ® glyph. If a font you like doesn't have one, you could try your hand at making one in a tool like [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/).